# Why clicking on the calculator button on my keyboard while inside cat doesnt show its value?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to bind keyboard keys to commands, and I successfully bound F12 and F10 to custom command. I did it using `cat` and then clicking that button which gave me `^[[24~^[[21~`.

Trying to do so with F11 or the calculator button gave nothing. It is somehow overriding this mechanism and goes straight to a pre-defined function. How can I bind it myself?

Comment: What is `cat`? The GNU/Linux `cat` command? F11 and calculator key are indeed defined by the desktop: you will need to remove these assignments first. How depends on the desktop you use.

Comment: Yes, the GNU `cat`. So each keyboard command first goes through a desktop button resolver that calls certain functions for F11 + calc, and only then is resolved via `bash's bind` ?